# gem install network_interface -v '0.0.1' errors Cygwin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, cygwin, metasploit

I'm trying to install metasploit in windows. When running the script in Cygwin, the network_interface gem won't install. I believe I have all the dependencies installed. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```
$ gem install network_interface -v '0.0.1'
ERROR:  Error installing network_interface:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb

[*] Running checks for netifaces code...
[*] Warning : this platform as not been tested
checking for getifaddrs()... no
checking for getnameinfo()... yes
checking for SIOCGIFCONF in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGSIZIFCONF in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGIFHWADDR in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGIFADDR in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGIFFLAGS in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGIFDSTADDR in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGIFBRDADDR in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGIFNETMASK in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGLIFNUM in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGLIFCONF in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGLIFFLAGS in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for net/if_dl.h... no
checking for netash/ash.h... no
checking for netatalk/at.h... no
checking for netax25/ax25.h... no
checking for neteconet/ec.h... no
checking for netipx/ipx.h... no
checking for netpacket/packet.h... no
checking for netrose/rose.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr.sa_len in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,net/if.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_at in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_ax25 in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_dl in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_eon in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_in in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_in6 in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_inarp in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_ipx in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_iso in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_ns in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_un in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_x25 in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_rose in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_ash in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_ec in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_ll in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_atmpvc in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_atmsvc in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_dn in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_irda in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_llc in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,netinet/in.h... no
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
generating network_interface_ext-x64-mingw32.def
compiling netifaces.c
netifaces.c: In function 'rbnetifaces_s_interface_info':
netifaces.c:794:11: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'strlen' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
In file included from c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winnt.h:1446:0,
                 from c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windef.h:137,
                 from c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:59,
                 from c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winsock2.h:23,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/win32.h:40,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/defines.h:153,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:70,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from netifaces.c:1:
c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/intrin.h:434:5: note: expected 'const char *'                         but argument is of type 'LPBYTE'
netifaces.c:794:11: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'rb_str_new' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
In file included from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1568:0,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from netifaces.c:1:
c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:674:7: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'LPBYTE'
netifaces.c:794:11: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'rb_str_new_cstr' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
In file included from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1568:0,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from netifaces.c:1:
c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:675:7: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'LPBYTE'
linking shared-object network_interface_ext.so
netifaces.o: In function `rbnetifaces_s_interface_info':
C:\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\network_interface-0.0.1\ext\network_interface_ext/netifaces.c:717: undefined reference to `GetAdapte                        rsInfo'
netifaces.o: In function `rbnetifaces_s_interfaces':
C:\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\network_interface-0.0.1\ext\network_interface_ext/netifaces.c:559: undefined reference to `GetAdapte                        rsInfo'
netifaces.o: In function `rbnetifaces_s_addresses':
C:\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\network_interface-0.0.1\ext\network_interface_ext/netifaces.c:238: undefined reference to `GetAdapte                        rsInfo'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [network_interface_ext.so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/network_interface-0.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/network_interface-0.0.1/ext/network_interface_ext/gem_make.out
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

user@KMIHOQRJOHE /opt/metasploit-framework
```